# Page_Init and Page_Load executes twice ASP & VB.NET only in IE .. why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, httpresponse, pageload

Having a strange problem today. I have managed to get my other problems fixed. My ASP page contains NO controls (so there are no blank image url's that could cause the problem). The program itself, from the VB code behind, gets binary data from a database and does a Response.BinaryWrite(imagedata) to the page. When I run it in Chrome or Firefox, everything works perfectly. When I run in IE, after my code finishes execution, it runs Page_Init again and Page_Load again as if loading for the very first time all over again. The value of postback is always false so there is no way around it. Here is the asp code (as you can see, nothing of interest)...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pagenamehere.aspx.vb" Inherits="x.x.x.x.y" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Page_Init and Page_Load signatures are as follows

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
'checks database connection string and handles error if there is one
End Sub

Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'checks user is authenticated to view the image and if so, does the binarywrite
End Sub
```

I have tried change autoeventwriteup to true and taking off the handles Me.Load etc but with no effect. I've also tried checking the Sender object but nothing changes between the first time the page loads and the unwanted second load of the page.

Lastly, the page loads for the second time straight after the following code

```
                Response.Clear()
                Response.ClearContent()
                Response.ClearHeaders()
                Response.Buffer = True
                Response.ContentType = "image/vnd.djvu"
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=temp.djvu")
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                Response.BinaryWrite(imagedata)
                Response.Flush()
                Response.Close()
```

Straight after Response.Close it will go back to Page_Init. I have tried response.end but it makes no difference. I have tried removing the header, the cache information etc but no luck. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Might be this causing the problem http://www.sitepoint.com/ie-contype-request/

Comment: try running fiddler and see if due to authentication, the page is getting called twice. If its not authentication, then you will still get to know why the second 'get' request is made

Comment: @jbl I believe you may be on to something. I have now got a temporary fix by doing the following: 1)Checking the content of the headers each time. The first time the code runs there are 7, the second time the code runs there are 6. The one which disappears the second time round is "Accept-Language". 2)Get the count of headers (7) and if it is less than 7 then this is the second time the code has run 3)only write to the database log if headers.keys.count < 7. The problem now is i want to improve the code and make it less hardcoded.Please advise further with vb.net example if possible? thx!

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/1ftllc.jpg please see picture for the first and second time the code runs. The link you provided suggests a PHP link and find out if the request is GETting the user-agent. I understand the majority of theory as to why this happens now but would very much appreciate a vb.net example/solution. once again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: After testing my code on 2 environments (Windows 7 / IE11 / Visual Studio 2012 && Windows XP / IE8 / VS2005) it appears that in both environments, the Accept-Language header will always be 'Nothing' the second time the code executes. I can use this information to work around my issue by checking if Accept-Language is Nothing and performing an If...Then. Thanks for the help; if you have any cleaner suggestions, please let me know. I checked the HTTP_USER_AGENT value as suggested but in both executions, it is the name of my browser string and never 'contype' as suggested. Thanks

Comment: If useragent is the same, only other suggestion I have is to compare `Request.HttpMethod` in both cases

Comment: Unfortunately they are both "GET" values each time the code executes, but thanks; I think I can use the value of the Accept-Language header to run my code based on the value :)

Comment: As a quick follow-up; my web app still won't run correctly on IE10 but works on IE11 and every IE up until IE8 (inclusive) with IE9 untested. When running in IE10, 2 GET requests are not made and I simply get an error icon (small black box with x in it) - any reason as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use `Response.Close` like that*.  It's really just for [protecting against attacks or other error-type conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx):

> This method terminates the connection to the client in an abrupt
>   manner and is not intended for normal HTTP request processing. The
>   method sends a reset packet to the client, which can cause response
>   data that is buffered on the server, the client, or somewhere in
>   between to be dropped.
>
> You might use this method in response to an attack by a malicious HTTP
>   client. However, typically you should call CompleteRequest instead if
>   you want to jump ahead to the EndRequest event and send a response to
>   the client.

And it will cause very similar problems to the one you're describing (because it sends a "reset" request to the client).  Try updating your code to use [Response.CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) instead, and this should (probably) resolve your "multiple request" issues.

**See this blog post for an in-depth analysis of why: [Response.End, Response.Close, and How Customer Feedback Helps Us Improve MSDN Documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx?Redirected=true)*

Comment: My bad, I quoted from the "Response.End" documentation before.  But the same advice still applies.